# Non-random assignment of values to a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

The R command

```
matrix(sample(1:9), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
```

produces

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    6    2
[2,]    9    1    8
[3,]    5    3    7
```

Values are placed within the matrix positions randomly.

How can I easily produce the following matrix (which is a simple rearrangement of the above)?

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
```

That is, in general, produce a matrix where small values tend to be near other small values and large values tend to be near other large values.

In other words, I would like to account for spatial autocorrelation among values in the matrix. Perhaps through specifying a correlation coefficient to indicate the overall strength of the relationship.

Comment: "That is, in general, produce a matrix where small values tend to be near other small values and large values tend to be near other large values." So you want to simulate values with spatial correlation?

Comment: @Roland Accounting for spatial autocorrelation is what I am getting at, though I should have explicitly stated it. Sorting values in a matrix is one way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a `sort` and then construct a `matrix`

```
matrix(sort(m1), 3, 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

---

Or we can do

```
m1[] <- sort(m1)
t(m1)
```

Comment: Simple enough .... Pertaining more to my second general question,  what if values were not sorted and smaller values (or larger) tended to occur at the top (or bottom) of the matrix?

Comment: @JarrettPhillips sorry, it is not clear about your question

Answer (score 1):

If what you need is to 'spread' a vector of numbers (or whatever) across this matrix you can do:

```
> matrix((1:9), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
> matrix((1:9), nrow = 3, ncol = 3,byrow = T)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
```

or with arbitrary numbers:

```
> vec <- c(12,17,-6,0.4,1,1,1,5,0)
> matrix(vec, nrow = 3, ncol = 3,byrow = T)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 12.0   17   -6
[2,]  0.4    1    1
[3,]  1.0    5    0
```